# Data structure in JS | Create reference to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reference

In my app, I have quizzes with questions. I'm writing a class whose goal is to load and concat quizzes. I have two arrays in my class.

The first array contains the quizz meta data :

```
metadata = [
  {
    name:'countries', 
    language:'French'
  },
  {
    name:'music', 
    language:'English'
  }
]
```

I also have an array containing all the questions concatenated:

```
questions = [
  {
    question:'What is the capital of France?', 
    metaIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question:'What is the capital of Poland?', 
    metaIndex: 0
  },
  ...
  {
    question:'Who is the singer of the Rolling Stones?', 
    metaIndex: 1
  }
]
```

As you can see, the questions contain a reference to the meta data index. It's like a foreign key in relational database. My problem is that if I remove the quiz 0, it will shift all the indexes, and I'll have to iterate through the questions to update the indexes.

In JS, is there a way to reference directly the object instead of the index?

Any general suggestion is welcome ;-)

Comment: *"It's like a foreign key in relational database."* - Not quite.  Because it's relying on index position rather than an identifying key.  What if you give the first array of objects unique keys, and the second array references those keys instead of their positional index?

Comment: I don't even understand why I didn't think of it in the first place.

Comment: Depending on how these data structures are created/used, you might even just include a direct reference to the relevant object instead of an identifier.  But there could be scenarios in which that doesn't quite work for you, which is why I haven't posted either approach as an answer.  At the moment I don't have an objective view on which would be "better".

Comment: Yes I already try to create a reference to the meta object, but for some obscure reason this is not a reference, but a copy of the object that is created. I guess this is one of the *scenarios* you are talking ;-) But your first solution is perfect for my app, and it also solves some other problems like asynchronous operations

Comment: *"for some obscure reason this is not a reference, but a copy of the object that is created"* - That definitely doesn't sound right, and probably worth investigating on its own (perhaps as a separate Stack Overflow question if necessary).  But if the first solution is working, I'll go ahead and add it as an answer below.

Comment: I perform some other operation like concatenation to append the next questions to the list. Maybe the problem comes from there. But it's OK, if you add the answer, I'll mark the question as best answer.

Comment: `for (const q of questions) q.meta = metadata[q.metaIndex]` will create the object references you are looking for; not copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's like a foreign key in relational database.

*Almost*.  Note that in a relational database, the *order* of returned records is not guaranteed unless explicitly defined.  It can change on any given SELECT.  (A subject which is often in question on Stack Overflow, but that's another conversation entirely.)  But in this case the second data structure is referencing the *positional index* of elements in the first.

If the index changes, either by changing the data or even simply sorting the data, that reference breaks.

The analogy of a relational database is a reasonable one though, all you have to do is update the implementation to match that analogy.  A foreign key references a primary key.  Simply add a primary key of some kind.  For example:

```
metadata = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name:'countries', 
    language:'French'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:'music', 
    language:'English'
  }
]
```

Then the second data structure can reference that:

```
questions = [
  {
    question:'What is the capital of France?', 
    metaID: 1
  },
  {
    question:'What is the capital of Poland?', 
    metaID: 1
  },
  {
    question:'Who is the singer of the Rolling Stones?', 
    metaID: 2
  }
]
```

That way the index/order/etc. of the former structure can change, but as long as the objects therein still have their `id` values then the latter is still referencing them.

In fact, if `name` is going to be unique in the former structure then *that* can be the identifier used.  (Though in the data shown I'm not assuming it would be, for example if there's a `countries` entry in `French` and another one in `English` then that value wouldn't be unique.)